# How to make individual hair strands wavy?

Tags: particles, hair

How to make individual hair strands wavy in Blender? I tried using the kink stuff but all that is very confusing to understand and it just makes the whole hair move in strange ways. I want to stop making the hair strands being so straight all the time. I want to add a soft wavyness to it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your question, you ask "individual". But what you want is to make all the hairs of a given particle system wavy right?

Comment: I have parent particles and children particles and I want those individual strands to be wavy. The strands themselfs, instead of creating a wavy pattern with the strands.